# RSelenium: Issue with extracting link from website

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium, getattribute

I am struggling to extract data from a website with `RSelenium` and would be grateful for any hint.

The site's address is `"https://www.airbank.cz/mapa-pobocek-a-bankomatu/brno-netroufalky-c-p-770/"`. The data/link i want to extract is:

```
<a class="flex items-center" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//50.659742,+14.039068/@50.659742,14.039068,16z/">
```

Below my code:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=483L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
x <- "https://www.airbank.cz/mapa-pobocek-a-bankomatu/brno-netroufalky-c-p-770/"

remDr$navigate(x)
Sys.sleep(5) # give the page time to fully load
current_url <- remDr$getCurrentUrl()
current_url
remDr$getStatus()
page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
class(page_source)
Sys.sleep(5) # give the page time to fully load

link_google <- page_source %>%
xml2::read_html() %>%
rvest::html_elements("a") %>%
rvest::html_attr("href")

str_subset(link_google, "dir")
character(0)
```

I am not sure why don't get the desired result (but other links). My suspicions is that it is related to the presence of an iframe, but I couldn't really figure it out.

When checking the raw result of  `page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` I actually can't find the link in question. However, when inspecting the site in my browser, the link is present.

Comment: Avoid using `getPageSource` since that will only give you the original page source, not the current state of the webpage after running all the javascript. Use `findElement` to find elements on the "current" version of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the *`href`* attribute i.e. `https://www.google.com/maps/dir//50.659742,+14.039068/@50.659742,14.039068,16z/` you can use the [`getElementAttribute`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seleniumPipes/versions/0.3.7/topics/getElementAttribute) method and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *css selector*:

  ```
  element <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "a.flex.items-center[href]")
  element$getElementAttribute("href")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//a[@class='flexitems-center' and @href]")
  element$getElementAttribute("href")
  ```

---

### Reference

[RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html)